# printing an increasing number along with the items of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a `list` in `python` - `['item1','item2','item3','item4']`. I am trying to print this list in following way - `1. ITEMS: item1 2. ITEMS: item2 3. ITEMS: item3 4. ITEMS: item4`. I wrote this code but this is giving error as I am trying to specify `range()` in wrong way:

```
list_semi = ["%d. ITEMS: %s" % (x for x in range(1,len(bookings)),items) for items in bookings]
print('Your items are {}.'.format(','.join(list_semi)))
```

`bookings` in the above code is the list whose sample data I have posted above. How can I print the list in the desired way as I have mentioned above?

**UPDATE CASE 2** If my sample input list changes to - `[[item1,price1],[item2,price2]...]` and I want the sample output as `1. ITEMS: item1, PRICE: price1 2. ITEMS: item2, PRICE: price2 3. ITEMS: item3, PRICE: price3 4. ITEMS: item4, PRICE: price4` then how should I frame my code? the list name is same as `bookings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `range`. Iterate on the list object directly, using `enumerate` to generate the indices. Specify the start parameter as 1:

```
>>> ' '.join(['{}. ITEMS: {}'.format(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1)])
'1. ITEMS: item1 2. ITEMS: item2 3. ITEMS: item3 4. ITEMS: item4'
```

---

**Update**:

```
>>> lst = [['item1','price1'],['item2','price2']]
>>> ' '.join(['{}. ITEMS: {}, PRICE: {}'.format(i, *x) for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1)])
'1. ITEMS: item1, PRICE: price1 2. ITEMS: item2, PRICE: price2'
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my desired output structure. I wanted to print `ITEMS: ` in front of each item. I have updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just so that I can understand how exactly it works suppose if I have a list of list - something like this -  `[[item1,price1],[item2,price2]...]` and I wanted to print them in `1. ITEMS: item1, PRICE: price1 2. ITEMS: item2, PRICE: price2 3. ITEMS: item3, PRICE: price3 4. ITEMS: item4, PRICE: price4`. How will the for loop structure change in that case? I know its an add on question but I am just asking so that I can understand how exactly it is working

Comment: @user2916886 Pal, it's not easy to read code in comments. You may update your question instead, and try not to throw in new assumptions (state the problem once) to avoid changing the answer again and again.

Comment: I apologise. I will update my question and add in this so that its helpful for me (and other too) to understand

Comment: I have updated my post above to include case 2 as well

Comment: @user2916886 It **unpacks** the inner lists and passes the two items for the last two placeholders in the format string.